# Ordinal del número cero

Tags: números, sufijos

Estoy escribiendo una librería en Node.js para transformar números a sus respectivos indicadores ordinales:

```
[
    "mo", // 10.º
    "ro", // 1.º
    "do", // 2.º
    "ro", // 3.º
    "to", // 4.º
    "to", // 5.º
    "to", // 6.º
    "mo", // 7.º
    "vo", // 8.º
    "no"  // 9.º
]
```

¿Cuál sería un sufijo/indicador que se podría usar para el número 0? Estoy pensando en simplemente devolver `"0"` pero tal vez hay una forma de escribirlo, así como el `0th / zeroth` en inglés.

Comment: If there is one, it is not common usage.  I've never heard "zeroth" in English.  It makes no sense to ever use an ordinal for zero in any language as far as I'm concerned.  I don't believe you will ever need to execute a line of code with zero as an ordinal, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Karlomanio "zeroth" is used a lot in mathematical and computer science terminology, but I don't know how extended it is to vernacular English.

Comment: @Karlomanio probably you should look up an dictionary before banning what  plenty of times does occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La lista de ordinales aparece en un artículo del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, entrada [*ordinales*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nypwukqZ6D64M23Yos). Allí no aparece el 0, así que uno se preguntaría si es que se lo olvidaron. Pero no, en Twitter la RAE explicó:

> #RAEconsultas **No existe un ordinal para el cero**. Aunque usted decidiera emplear una forma como «0.º», no contaría con una equivalencia con la que pudiera leerse o reproducirse en palabras.
>
> <sub>RAE [@RAEinforma, 5 diciembre 2017 en Twitter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/938003749724983296)</sub>

Dado que en Matemáticas siempre hablamos del enésimo, por *n*, podríamos decir que el 0.º es el *ceroésimo*. En cualquier caso, no sé si demasiada gente te entendería.

Answer (score 1):

No se utiliza una forma ordinal para el cero, sino que simplemente tomamos el cardinal (de modo idéntico a como hacemos con los papas) como correctamente menciona fedorqui en su respuesta. Así, ***zeroth*** law of thermodynamics puede traducirse como → *principio **cero** de la termodinámica*. Como se ve, no es realmente necesario calcar una forma inglesa para expresar el concepto, sino que podemos simplemente circunlocutarlo.

Dicho lo anterior, como usuario de mi lengua, me he tomado la libertad de crear un protologismo para traducir *zeroth*, solo por el gusto de hacerlo.

**nuleno**

Este término está formado mediante el préstamo de *nullus* y el sufijo *-eno*. Guarda además relación con el francés *nullième*.

La Wikilengua [dice](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/N%C3%BAmero_ordinal#Formaci.C3.B3n_regular) que el sufijo *-ésimo* solo se utiliza en las decenas, lo que lo descarta para el cero; por tanto, formas como *cerésimo* serían incorrectas. ¿Por qué el préstamo del latín? Por analogía con *primero*, *segundo*, *vigésimo*, etcétera. La Wikilengua [también dice](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/N%C3%BAmero_ordinal#Formaci.C3.B3n_regular) que:

> Al contrario que en otras lenguas, en español los ordinales no se forman a partir de los cardinales de modo regular […]. Se trata de cultismos, es decir, adaptaciones del latín, y como tales carecen de amplio uso (salvo en los primeros, hasta décimo o un poco más).